# Seeking map of communes for Bavaria region before 1930

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, history, germany

I am looking into data for an article, and I am missing a pretty important map. The map relates to [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26048/were-there-communes-in-imperial-germany/26050#26050/) question. I need a map of Bavaria communes, the so-called Gemeinden divisions, either to buy or freely available, in raster or vector format. I would accept any format that can be imported into GIS software, but it needs to represent the period before 1930.

I have spent around 5 hours already and all I could find related to the map I am looking for is in the link to the other question. I mean I found other sites, and old books, but nothing concrete.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a period before and during the [**Weimarer Republik**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimarer_Republik).

I would suggest the following sources:

- [bavarikon](https://www.bavarikon.de/)
- [Die Bayerische Staatsbibliothek](https://www.bayerische-landesbibliothek-online.de/histkarten)
- [Bayerisches Landesamt für Statistik](https://www.statistik.bayern.de/statistik/gebietbevoelkerung/)
- [Historisches Lexikon Bayerns](https://www.historisches-lexikon-bayerns.de/Lexikon/Hauptseite)

Comment: And maybe this one? https://maps.arcanum.com

Comment: Or this : https://www.oldmapsonline.org/ It allows to zoom to a region of interest, then search for maps from a certain time period. Same principle here: https://www.kartenportal.ch/